Storing checkbox values for output in Shiny
I was trying to get a sense for how checkbox group input values can be stored in R shiny. I want to condition on them on the server side. Let's say my goal is the following- the user gets to check one to three fruits (Apple, Orange, Banana). Subsequently, based on the input, the app prints outputs. If 'Apple' is included in the input, it prints 'Apples are great!'. Otherwise it prints 'Please include an apple daily'.
I am including my sample code below. Right now it gives me an error for the %in% function, saying 'match needs vector arguments'. I would appreciate any help with fixing the code, and also to better understand how to store checkbox inputs as reactive variables on the server side. Thank you!
information <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")
ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("info", "Select your fruit of choice", information),
)
server <- function(input, output, session){y <- reactive(input$info)
if("Apple" %in% y){print("Apples are great!")}
else{print("Please include an apple daily")}
}
shinyApp(ui, server)


Your storage of the checkbox values is suitable. Since this defines a reactive, you can only read the values inside a reactive context, you can learn more about it e.g. in Mastering Shiny. Below therefore your if is wrapped inside an observe.
Furthermore, the reactive has to be accessed using (), so we have to use y() instead of y.
library(shiny)

information <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("info", "Select your fruit of choice", information)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  y <- reactive(input$info)
  
  observe({
    if ("Apple" %in% y()) {
      print("Apples are great!")
    }
    else{
      print("Please include an apple daily")
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)


Thanks for your help. By the way- are you aware of how I can refer to an input vector's entry positions within a conditional panel? I tried something like condition = "input.info[1] = 'Apple'" for instance. However, this fails. Basically I want the condition to be that the first entry is Apple. Any simple way to do this?
